# ERROR: Database lock

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sqlite

This is the delete function which i used to delete in sqlite database so i am seeing a exception database is locked.
Here's my Code :

```
    Dim con As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source= " & AppSettings.DbName & ";Version=3;")

    Try
        con.Open()
        Dim strQuery As String = "DELETE FROM Externalsupplier_Capablity WHERE ID =  @id "  ' WHERE Vendor_no = @VendorNo"
        Dim cmd As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(strQuery, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", DbType.String).Value = TxtdeleteID.Text
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(strQuery)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred: " & ex.Message)

    Finally
        con.Close()
        con.Dispose()


    End Try
```

Comment: The problem is that some other command/query was not closed.

Comment: Ok.. How to check whether its closed or not ?

Comment: Check all other commands.

Comment: Thanks its working now !